# Django: simple way to validate combinations of fields?

Tags: python, django, forms, validation

In Django, the way to test things like

a) at least one of two fields has been filled in, and if not to place an error message; or

b) because one field has been filled in, another one becomes required, and put an error message on the now-required field

is to test for that in the `form.clean` method.

This is a common, and repetitive task. Is there a library which simplifies the writing of such tests within `clean`? Preferably one which is declarative-ish?

Answer (score 0):

I would be surprised if there is a library to do this, since it would be very difficult to generalize. For example, I construct very specific error messages to make sure the user knows what is going on: "Since you filled out X and Y, you must also include a Z."

In your case, however, it may be worth taking the time to do this yourself. If I were to do it, I would create a subclass of BaseForm to use in these cases. Here is a very rough outline (not tested):

```
class CrossRequirementsForm(BaseForm):

    # subclasses set this attribute:
    # cross_requirements_fields = {'foo': ('bar', 'baz',), 'height': ('weight',)}

    def clean(self):
        if self.cross_requirements_fields:
            for required_field, if_other_fields = self.cross_requirements_fields.items():
                if all([self.cleaned_data[f] for f in if_other_fields]):
                    if not self.cleaned_data[required_field]:
                        raise ValidationError('{} is required since {} are set'.format(
                            required_field, if_other_fields
                        ))
```

Then, your subclasses could just do:

```
class MyForm(CrossRequirementsForm):
    cross_requirements_fields = {'foo': ('bar', 'baz',), 'height': ('weight',)}
```

and if they override clean, make sure to call super.clean.

Comment: I feel some functional programming coming on

Comment: I do whatever I can to keep our codebase clean, since it allows us to iterate faster and that is extremely important to our business. My background is in Lisp :)

Comment: Specifically, functional idioms in python should allow composition of functionals which specify behaviour.

Answer (score -1):

You can write simple mixin for forms like:

```
from django.core import forms

class AwesomeFormMixin(object):
    def clean(self):
        for field in self.fields_to_process:
            #process fields here


class MyForm(AwesomeFormMixin, forms.Form):
    fields_to_process = ['this_field', 'that_field']
    ...        
    def clean(self):
        super(MyForm, self).clean()
        ...
    ...
```